# How to store bcrypt data using Make request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bcrypt

This is how I would make such a function
Controller code

```
    public function store(RegistrationStoreRequest $request){

    $user = User::create($request->validated());

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->home();

}
```

This is my Request form code

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email', 
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create a value mutator:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
   $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

however you need to ensure you never prehash the password.

2. Hash in controller

```
 public function store(RegistrationStoreRequest $request){

    $user = User::create(array_merge(Arr::except($request->validated(), 'password'), [ 'password' => Hash::make($request->password) ]));

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->home();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most clean way is to use a custom cast for password field, first create UserPasswordCast.php class:

```
<?php

//app/Casts/UserPasswordCast.php

namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserPasswordCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        //return hashed value
        return Hash::make($value);
    }
}
```

Suggested location:

> app/Casts/UserPasswordCast.php

Then update your 'user' model to use this cast, add "$casts" array or update it if existed:

```
use App\Casts\UserPasswordCast;

...

protected $casts = [

    ...

    'password' => UserPasswordCast::class
];
```

That's it, you don't have to worry about password again

Just save your user model as it:

```
public function store(RegistrationStoreRequest $request)
{

    $user = User::create($request->validated());

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->home();

}
```

For more info please check:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

Answer (score 0):

```
=>create method function add in User.php(Model).

public static function create($user, $request)
    { 
        if (isset($request->name)) {
            $user->name = $request->name;
        }
        if (isset($request->email)) {
            $user->email = $request->email;
        }

        if (isset($request->password)) {
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        }

        if (isset($request->confirmpassword)) {
            $user->confirmpassword = $request->confirmpassword;
        }
        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }

=>New user create with validate your all request field.

public function store(RegistrationStoreRequest $request){

    $user = User::create(New User,$request);

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->home();

}

Please try this code it is working.
```